# Nominate questions for re-open

Tags: discussion, general-reference

Now that a [consensus](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2400/98) is that there shouldn't be any closure of questions that are marked general reference, please nominate your favorite questions for re-open.

If you have sufficient privileges, just cast a re-open vote, otherwise, feel free to post here. Also, if you feel the question needs to have a case made for it, please feel free to post the question here.

You can find a list of all GR questions [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/85868/questions-that-are-closed-as-general-reference), note that some of  them may have already been reopened.

Comment: Can't t his be handled via the review queue? This seems rather cumbersome.

Comment: Hence the nominate for re-open if you can. There might be some users that don't have the reputation to do so, or some controversial re-opens, which is where I would put this at.

Comment: "Just case a re-open vote, otherwise, feel free to post here" - VTROs bump the question?  I did not know this...

Comment: @Izkata: A vote to re-open will put the question into a review queue, where everyone with the required reputation can take a look at the question and decide if it merits re-opening.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4830/who-was-sifo-dyas

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25215/did-they-have-witches-in-oz-before-dorothys-era

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18505/who-took-care-of-teddy