# Should we reopen "general reference" questions as a matter of course?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

After the decision was taken to [burninate General Reference](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2400/should-we-burninate-general-reference), the close reason was removed but I keep coming across questions that were closed for this reason. [This one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24991/what-was-the-entity-looking-for-that-took-voyager-into-the-delta-quadrant), for example.

Given that this close reason no longer exists and that pretty much all of these questions would be currently acceptable, **should we make a point of reopening them *as a matter of course* when we encounter them?**

**Should we go further and reopen all of them?**

Comment: I see no reason not to reopen them if you see one but I see no reason to put in effort finding and opening them.

Comment: Looking for more rep, eh? ;)

Comment: @SQB - Always and forever.

Comment: As a side note, questions that were closed as general reference are often still worth **downvoting** if not closing. "This question does not show any research effort", as it says on the tooltip for the downvote button.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Oh, indeed. And the point that many of them deserve re-closing *for different reasons* is well made. There aren't that many (less than twenty remaining) so I'll start adding them to the queue over the next couple of days.

Comment: We don't go back and mass-close questions that are now close-worthy but weren't 5 years ago. I see no reason to do the reverse either.

Comment: @KutuluMike - I suspect that's because it's much harder to identify closeworthy questions.

Answer (score 6):

**If you find a closed question which you think should be reopened, vote to reopen it.**

I hesitate to make any sweeping statements about a whole class of questions; doubtless some GR-closed questions will be worth reopening and some won't.

It's likely that *most* of them should be reopened according to today's standards - or possibly reopened and then closed for a different reason - but they should still be considered on a case-by-case basis. There's no such thing as a mass close-vote or mass reopen-vote; by the way the system is designed, **questions have to be closed or reopened individually**, and this is a good thing.

Without having looked at all questions closed as "general reference", I can't possibly say whether they should *all* be reopened. But if you think they should, feel free to cast reopen votes on all of them (preferably **not all at once** though - let's not flood the Reopen Votes review queue too badly) and wait to see how the rest of the community votes on them.

Comment: I've been adding them to the queue as I go through the old questions stack. I've not seen any that shouldn't be added, nor any that have proved contentious when added. Basically they all seem to get reopened.

Comment: Just remember that reopening a question bumps it to the frontpage. ;-)

Comment: @Cahir Sure; that's another reason not to do them all at once.

Comment: I'm working my way through the historic questions stack. Since this answer seems the preferred choice,  I shall flag them as I come across them rather than systematically reopening them

Comment: @Valorum By 'flag', do you mean VTRO? Since you have more than 3k rep, I can't see why you'd raise a flag rather than simply using your vote to put the question into the Reopen Votes review queue.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - By "flag", I meant VTRO.