# Why was this "general reference" question kept closed?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, closed-questions, general-reference, vote-to-reopen

This question

- **[Where did Doc Brown get plutonium from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17308/how-did-doc-brown-steal-plutonium)**

Was originally closed as "General Reference", presumably because the answer was largely covered in the same scene in the film.

Since ["general reference" has been burninated](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2400/should-we-burninate-general-reference) and is no longer a valid close reason (and given that the answer is actually rather more interesting than simply saying "**The Libyans got it *somehow***") I added it to the re-open queue.

The [timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/17308/timeline) indicates that it then received three votes to reopen and **three votes to remain closed.**

[image]

**Why?**

Comment: No clue. Might be worthwhile to include more of the timeline, to show that it has been through the reopen review several times.

Comment: Since being closed, it's been through the Reopen Votes review queue **four times**: [once in 2012](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/4609) (3x Leave Closed), [once in 2014](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/31178) (3x Leave Closed), [once in 2015](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/61638) (3x Leave Closed, 1x Reopen), [once in 2016](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/93616) (3x Leave Closed, 3x Reopen). A total of **eight users** have VTROed it over the years, one user doing so twice at different times.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Indeed. And if it were asked today, I can't imagine it would get closed.

Comment: National security

Comment: @Hack-R - It's not that easy to steal plutonium, I can assure you

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Am I just being dense? This was reopened, then seems to have gone back to the review queue but I [can't see who put it there](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/94073).

Comment: @Valorum - i'm tempted to ask if you have a junior novelization of "How to steal Plutonium for Dummies" :)

Comment: @Valorum It was put back in the review queue due to a close *flag* from a <3k rep user, rather than a close *vote*.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Ah, that explains it. I thought I was going mad.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - I have the Despicable Me junior novel. It's more of a "how to" guide...

Comment: @Valorum Perhaps you are :-)